# Some webdesign questions

Tags: html, css

Hello I have created a basic layout in html and css,
1) Could you tell me if I can Improve the css or html?
2) I'd like the site to work in rages of 1024x768 and up.
3) How can I remove the horizontal scroll bars.
4) What is the simple meaning of the em unit?

Thanks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="center">
    <div id="header">Title</div>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    <div id="warp">
        <div id="slider">#slider</div>
        <div id="posts">#posts</div>
        <div id="sidebar">#sidebar</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">#footer</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    background-color:#ededed;
}
#header{
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#666;
    /*Text*/
    font-size:24px;
    background: #2989d8;
}
#center{
    margin:0 auto;
}

#warp{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:70em;
    background-color:#444;/*#e3e3e3;*/
    margin: -35px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
#slider{
    margin: 2em auto;
    width:65em;
    height:20em;
    background-color:#555;
}
#posts{
    float:left;
    width: 50em;
    height:50em;
    background-color:#111;
}
#sidebar{
    float:left;
    height:50em;
    width:20em;
    background-color:#777;
}
#footer{
    clear:both;
    height: 60px;
    width: 40em;
    margin:1em;
    background-color: #666;
    /*Text*/
    font-size:24px;
}
```

Comment: em is equal to the "m" in any given font with relation to size!

Comment: for horizonatl scrolbar use overflow: none;

Comment: Is it your intention that the `footer` is not centered like `warp`?

Comment: for pages working is different resolution use media quiries!

Comment: you are missing the meta in your head in the markup

Comment: and since you are using HTML5, use the header, footer, nav, article and section elements, instead of all those div!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unfortunately don't think this can be considered as a useful question for others, and I'm pretty sure you are using a template you are not sure how to work around. Here are the (quick) answers to your (quick) questions:

1) The css and html look fine, except for the missing elements in the head. You should also give #center a width to make sure it works in all browsers.

2) as Jawad mentioned, @media. You can find lots of information on this site or others. Check [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/).

3) Not sure, difficult to see without a live example or http://jsfiddle.net/. Could be the overflow/widths.

4) em= Unit of measurement in the field of typography, equal to the currently specified point size. Google.

But if you are new to css, I recommend you visit these questions/answers or look for other ones so you can create good-looking and good-functioning websites.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500827/what-css-tips-should-every-beginning-developer-know-about

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132587/the-best-css-tutorial-site-blog-book

Comment: Actually I wrote this myself, only with a bit of help from help from Google, I got it working but I wanted to understand the fundamentals because I am not a web designer(yet). Thanks Anyways. +1

Comment: That´s great then! I thought it was a template because it has lots of different elements. Keep working, you are doing great.